# How to disable Server Side Includes (SSI) using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, security, ssi, server-side-includes, shtml

The ServerSide Include(SSI) has been enabled on my server. But,I do not want it get executed in my folder. So, I wanted to add a .htaccess file to disable SSI in that folder.How do I do it?
I tried

```
 RemoveHandler server-parsed .shtml
```

but its not working.How do I achieve it?

Comment: I do not have permissions for the server configuration files,so I have to depend on .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your use of `RemoveHandler` does not make sense. [The documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#removehandler) says that the syntax is `RemoveHandler extension [extension] ...`, which means that besides removing the handler for files ending with `.shtml`, you are also removing the handler for files ending with `server-parsed`.

A handler is a way to tell Apache that for certain files, it should be interpreted by an other program, instead of straight send to the user. For example, a handler for files ending for `.php` would send the file through a php parser first. Removing this handler would expose the php code in that file to the browser instead. <s>As far as I know `.shtml` files are not interpreted by anything, so removing the handler that does not exist for these files will not help you in any way.</s> Actually, if configured right, Apache takes care of `.shtml` files itself. This is not done by a handler, but by some internal options. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html).

What you seem to want to do is send a HTTP 403: Forbidden error code when someone tries to directly access your file. There are some ways you can accomplish this, for example by using `mod_rewrite` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)). Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled, then add the following to `.htaccess` in your document root:

```
#We first need to make sure that we want to rewrite
RewriteEngine on

#Forbid access to all files ending with `.shtml`
RewriteRule \.shtml$ - [F,L]
```

Since internal includes do not care what mod_rewrite does, that works just fine. `RewriteRule` executes for all requests that matches the first argument. The second argument (`-`) means that the url is not being rewritten. The `F` flag lets Apache know to send the Forbidden error and the `L` flag lets mod_rewrite know that it should stop this rewrite cycle. I don't think it will start a new rewrite cycle when the request is forbidden, since no script will be executed when the forbidden error is sent.

Comment: thanks @sumurai8 .Sorry,I was not clear in my question.I want to allow access to the .shtml files,but I do not want the commands in it executed.(like include,exec). So,I used remove handler,hoping to stop the parser.Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: `Options -Includes` should do the trick I suppose. I am not sure why you save the files as shtml in the first place then though.

Answer (score 0):

Complate Turn off/Disable Server Side Includes and CGI Execution in Apache Webserver:

**Solution :**

Steps to turn off server side includes (mod_include)
And CGI execution
Modify the **httpd.conf** apache main configuration file or **.htaccess**.
This can be applied to root directory or specific directory

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```

if you want using in **.htaccess**. make one .htaccess before root directory (public_html) and add this :

```
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks -Includes -ExecCGI
```